# How to count occurrence of two events and then display the percentage of uplift and get just the metric in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have installed elasticsearch and kibana in my local Linux OS. I am trying to visualise the percentage of uplift between two events.

So first I need to count the occurrences of the events and then perform the basic calculation for uplift. I am using the visual builder to make the visualisation, but there I am unable to input to dynamic values.

Can anyone please tell how to implement the same or if there is any other way to calculate the uplift and show the metric value in dashboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Elasticsearch Painless scripting in order to achieve this, on ES query level. Read the docs. here are some examples:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-examples.html